# XBOX Control PLC

Tags: robotics, plc, xbox

I'm working on a project that allows a user to look through a camera that's mounted on a robot using the Oculus Rift. There's just one problem, the user needs to be able to control the robot using an XBOX Controller.

My question is: How do I send commands to a [PLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller) with an XBOX Controller.

Comment: You might want to ask this question here: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

This question is impossible to answer. It is just to generic.
It is like. "I want to build a villa with a nice garden. What do I need?".

Start with the beginning.

What type of PLC are you using?
Do you know some infomration what sort of protocols can be send from the Xbox?
How can you program in the Xbox that it can communicate. Which types of pyshical bus types and protocols can be used or designed? Like ethernet, RS232, USB etc. etc..
Idem for the PLC being used.
Etc. etc. etc..

If yoy then encounters some specific problems, like how can connect an active low RS232 connection to an active high RS232 for Xbox to PLC, we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a **KUKA robot** you could use a PC and a TCP/IP connection instead of having to connect to a PLC using

1. Java through https://github.com/aauc-mechlab/JOpenShowVar,
2. Convert the origin C++ source that the above uses to fit your needs: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openshowvar/

There are some students at our school that will do the same thing this fall ^^
They will use Java and JOpenShowVar.